# Calendar app on Desire - Can I get Stock Android Calendar?

Tags: htc-desire, calendar

So i'm pretty sick of the calendar app on my HTC Desire... it's good, and does most things well, but something it does badly which is just really a stupid oversight by htc is this:  The date picker does not show the day of the picked date.  Even when you have selected the date, the event you're creating doesn't tell you the day.  WTF??

I guess i should ask if this is the same onthe stock android calendar app?  If not, how can i get that one on my desire?

I'm very tempted to ditch the HTC ROM and install a Gingerbread ROM... the running out of space issue is beyond a joke too.  ugh!

thanks heaps
greg

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the HTC Sense calendar, which is different from the regular calendar.  To replace it:

1. Root your phone.
2. Use a file manager like Root Explorer to back up any files you replace and to copy in new ones.  You'll need to browse to /system/app and mount it as R/W.
3. Use an AOSP (android-open-source-project) calendar like [this one from XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=6472313&postcount=674) (has instructions).  It's for 2.1, it might work for 2.2 but if not just search XDA for another.

Comment: Thanks for the info... i will root my phone soon, but figure i'll just put a gingerbread rom on there.. i think i want to get rid of all the sense gunk.

Comment: i'm also very tempted to buy a nexus s... not because its an amazing phone (its not - why no SD card???), but because it's the only option with a pure google android experience... i'm getting the feeling the manufacturers introduce more issues than  its worth by modding their android versions. :|

Comment: By the way i found Calengoo app, which is excellent.  I think i'll just use this from now on, until i get to rooting my phone and getting rid of sense ui. :)